# Getting the coordinates on the edges of the map in view

Tags: javascript, gis, here-api, heremaps

I have a simple map (taken from the documentation) which is centered at a point

```
function moveMapToBerlin(map){
  map.setCenter({lat:52.5159, lng:13.3777});
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```

Is there a way to get the coordinates of the edge points of the map in display? ie the coordinates of all the 4 corners? I am trying to draw a rectangle automatically from what the user can see. (Without the user having to manually get the coordinates of the corners)

[image: Image of the map]

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `bounds` property from [H.map.ViewModel.html#getLookAtData()](https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.20.0/api_reference/H.map.ViewModel.html#getLookAtData):

```js
let rect = new H.map.Polygon(map.getViewModel().getLookAtData().bounds);
map.addObject(rect);
```